# Swift - programmatically trigger NSSearchField filtering

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, nssearchfield, tablefilter

I'm writing a table-based app for MacOS (using `NSTableView`).

To implement table filtering, I use **bindings**.
In my app I have a `NSTableView` that I bind to a `NSArrayController`, and a `NSSearchField` that I bind to that same array controller.
This is my code for binding these objects:

```swift
self.tableView.bind(.content, to: self.arrayController, withKeyPath: "arrangedObjects", options: nil)
let searchField = (Constants.appDelegate.SearchFieldVC.view as? NSSearchField)!  // grab searchField reference
searchField.bind(
    .predicate,
    to: self.arrayController,
    withKeyPath: NSBindingName.filterPredicate.rawValue,
    options: [.predicateFormat: "col CONTAINS[cd] $value"]
)
```

where `col` is the name of my tableView column that I want the search field to filter.

Everything works perfectly fine; when I type text into my search field it filters the table accordingly.
The problem emerges when I try to **programmatically** "inject" text into my search field.
This is the code I use to do that:

```swift
self.view.window?.makeFirstResponder(searchField) // move focus from tableView to searchField
searchField?.stringValue.append(someString)  // inject some text into searchField, expecting immediate table filtering
searchField?.currentEditor()?.moveToEndOfLine(self)
```

Meaning - I make my searchField the first responder (moving "focus" from the table view to the search field), then write some text into the search field's stringValue.
When I run the application, **I can see the "focus" moving to my searchField and the text being written into it, but no filtering is being executed**. I have to either manually press "Enter" or keep typing inside the searchField for the filter to execute correctly.

How can I programmatically inject text into my searchField AND execute it's filtering capabilities immediately?
Thanks!

Comment: Try to call `validateEditing()` on the search field after setting the `stringValue`

Comment: @vadian That does not change anything, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding is triggered by the action.

```
searchField.sendAction(searchField.action, to: searchField.target)
```

`searchField.action` and `searchField.target` can be `nil`.